# Network unavailable inside udev shell script

Tags: linux, networking, bash, fedora, udev

I have the custom shell script executed when FireWire device connected/disconnected from my PC. Script executed successfully but I found network unavailable inside this script.

Here is my .rule:

```
[root@ rules.d]# cat 99-superuser.rules  
ACTION=="remove", KERNEL=="fw*1", SUBSYSTEM=="firewire", RUN+="/root/remove.bash"
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="fw*1", SUBSYSTEM=="firewire",RUN+="/root/add.bash"
```

Here is my bash script:

```
[root@ rules.d]# cat /root/remove.bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
nslookup superuser.com 8.8.8.8 >> /root/udev.log 2>&1
```

And this is what it prints to /root/udev.log after device disconnected:

```
[root@ rules.d]# cat /root/udev.log 
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

In the same time if I execute command manually from the console:

```
[root@ rules.d]# nslookup superuser.com 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   superuser.com
Address: 151.101.1.69
```

I'm absolutely confused. How it gonna be happen?
SELinux disabled.
firewall fisabled.
Fedora 28 updated.

Any suggestions?

**UDP:**

Thanks to [grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity) - fixed by changing **IPAddressDeny=any** to **IPAddressAllow=any** in systemd-udevd.service file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The udev service is configured to use seccomp filters to limit what sockets can be created (although this has been relaxed recently to allow inet/inet6), as well as cgroup BPF socket filters to limit what IP addresses packets may be sent to/received from.

Specifically, the options in systemd-udevd.service:

```
[Unit]
# Attaches a cgroup-wide eBPF socket filter
IPAddressDeny=any
```

Comment: Thanks! I fixed! I comment out IPAddressDeny and add IPAddressAllow=any to the .service file. Not sure if this change will not be removed after dnf update but at least issue resolved.

Comment: Would be good to know more about the security implications of this.